# Qt- fill circle with images

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I've tried to fill circle with four images. Firstly , each photo brush in the same size ,hereafter scale final image with that size. But result is not what I want.

At the moment circle in foreground and photos on background, like here:
[image]

How to fill circle with photos and remove rectangle?

Here is my code:

```
QPixmap *CGlobalZone::profPicFromFourPics(QList<QPixmap> pixmapList)
{
        QPixmap *avatar = NULL;
        QImage roundedImage(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M*2, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M*2, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        roundedImage.fill(Qt::transparent);
        QBrush brush0(pixmapList[0]);
        QBrush brush1(pixmapList[1]);
        QBrush brush2(pixmapList[2]);
        QBrush brush3(pixmapList[3]);
        QPainter painter(&roundedImage);
        QPen pen(QColor(176, 216, 242), 1);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        painter.setBrush(brush0);
        painter.drawRect(0 , 0 , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M  , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M  );
        painter.setBrush(brush1);
        painter.drawRect(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M , 0 , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M*2  , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M  );
        painter.setBrush(brush2);
        painter.drawRect(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M*2  , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M*2  );
        painter.setBrush(brush3);
        painter.drawRect(0 , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M*2  , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M*2  );
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M*2-3 , CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M*2-3 );
        avatar  = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(roundedImage).scaled(QSize(CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M, CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M),
                                                    Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
       return avatar;
}
```

Comment: `QPixmap::setMask` ?

Comment: How to use QPixmap::setMask on this question? @Amartel

Comment: You need to create `QBitmap`, which contains `1`, where you want to draw and `0`, where - not. You can use `Qt::color1` and `Qt::color0` for this. Since `QBitmap` inherits `QPixmap`, you can draw a circle on it, using `QPainter`. Or you can load it from file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in the following way (details in source comments):

```
// The avatar image. Should be four, but use one for demonstration.
QPixmap source("avatar.png");

// Initialize the avatar and bring it to a standard size.
// This step may be skipped if avatars have the same sizes.
const int width = CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M;
const int height = CGlobalZone::AVATAR_HEIGHT_M;
source = source.scaled(width, height);

// Set up the final image that contains four avatar images.
QPixmap target(2 * width, 2 * height);
target.fill(Qt::transparent);

QPainter painter(&target);

// Set clipped region (circle) in the center of the target image
QRegion r(QRect(width / 2, height / 2, width, height), QRegion::Ellipse);
painter.setClipRegion(r);

painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, source);          // First avatar
painter.drawPixmap(width, 0, source);      // Second avatar
painter.drawPixmap(0, height, source);     // Third avatar
painter.drawPixmap(width, height, source); // Fourth avatar

target.save("test.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [painter paths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html) for the task. Rather than drawEllipse you should do

```
int dim = CGlobalZone::AVATAR_WIDTH_M*2;
QPainterPath entirePath;
QPainterPath ellipsePath;

entirePath.addRect(0, 0, dim, dim);
ellipsePath.addEllipse(0, 0, dim-3, dim-3);
QPainterPath outOfEllipse = entirePath.subtracted(ellipsePath);
painter.fillPath(outOfEllipse, QBrush(Qt::transparent));
```

**edit:** Because `QPainterPath` is for complex cases, you should use `QRegion`. After testing I found out there might small pixel errors when filling inside and outside the same path (in your case it is going to be fine).

Comment: `QRegion` is a bad idea, it's like storing a monochrome mask. It won't ever look good other than for rectangular areas.

Comment: `QRegion` did render better for a simple inside outside circle fill. But I don't have much experience using it.